# How to do fetch in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good afternoon, I get json from the server, I process it, but the call to render occurs 2 times.Google, make an empty object in the constructor.And if the object has no property, then undefined is returned, but I also have arrays, from which the application crashes.I attach the code. How to get the data out of the state? Is it possible to fetch in the render and write?

```
export default class Forma extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: [] };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => this.setState({ data: result }))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

    return <h1>{console.log(data.goals[0].gs_id)}</h1>; //падает
  }
}
```

Comment: don't do `console.log` use `return <h1>{data.goals[0].gs_id}</h1> //падает` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`, it's deprecated.

And that's a really good addition in Christopher's answer to handle async operation.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result =>
        this.setState({
          data: result
        })
      )
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

    return <h1> {data[0] ? data[0].title : 'Loading'} </h1>;
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thanks @Dhaval, I think either of our solutions would work well for OP.

Comment: Absolutely :) @ChristopherNgo

Answer (score 4):

Use an extra state-value that you can toggle when the data has finished fetching. That will help prevent the attempt of using an object property inside an empty array.

```
export default class Forma extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      data: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => this.setState({ loading: false, data: result }))
      .catch(e => {
        this.setState({ loading: false })
        console.log(e)
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, data } = this.state;

    if (loading) {
      return <span>Loading</span>;
    }

    if (!data || data.length === 0) {
      return <span>No items found</span>;
    }

    return <h1>{data.goals[0].gs_id}</h1>;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are rendering a `console.log`?

Comment: Lol :) probably best to read the code to not have those kinds of copy paste issues :D all good though. I reverted to a +1

Comment: @JohnRuddell Lol I don't think my other answers are worthy of more than just 1 upvote lol.

Comment: @JohnRuddell, now I feel like a heathen for not using a prettifier haha

Comment: You're good! :) just helping out so passers by in the future can read more easily <3